# Error in chi square simulation - cannot allocate memory block of size 134217728 Tb

Tags: r, simulation, chi-squared

I am running the following function on my data and I keep getting an error relating to the memory block size. My data is not that big (800 rows, 3 columns), and the function only works when I reduce it to 300 rows.

```
SSAS <- function(x, conf.int = 0.95, B = 10000)
{
x <- as.matrix(x)
nr <- nrow(x)
nc <- ncol(x)
sr <- rowSums(x)
sc <- colSums(x)
n <- sum(x)
E <- outer(sr, sc, "*")/n
dimnames(E) <- dimnames(x)
tmp <- .Call(stats:::C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E)
obs <- sum(sort((x - E)^2/E, decreasing = TRUE))/n
sim <- tmp/n
p0 <- (1 - conf.int)/2
return(c(obs, quantile(sim, p0), quantile(sim, 1 -p0)))
}
```

Error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>          cannot allocate memory block of size 134217728 Tb

However, when I use the trial data provided, which is larger (over 1000 rows) - the function works fine.

```
cap <- read.table("http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/R/donnees/mfdcapreolus.txt",
h = T)

l1 <- splitmfd(cap)
w <- matrix(unlist(lapply(l1, SSAS)), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
```

(splitmfd)

```
splitmfd <- function(mfd) {
 loca1 <- function(x) {
  x <- t(x[, 1:2])
  dimnames(x) <- list(c("mal", "fem"), as.character(1:ncol(x)))
  x
 }
 l0 <- split(mfd, mfd$mon)
 lapply(l0, loca1)
}
```

My data looks like this: (Instead of months 1-12 as in the sample, I have split it into 3 periods - Prenurse, Nurse, and PostNurse)

```
> head(groups)
  X n_male_mat n_fem_mat  PERIOD
1 1          0        22 PRENURS
2 2          0        14 PRENURS
3 3          4        19 PRENURS
4 4          1         0 PRENURS
5 5          0        21   NURSE
6 6          0        11   NURSE
```

Comment: Sorry, but the C function is not designed for such large data. It was written for the `chisq.test` function and contingency tables are usually not that large.

Comment: Did you try with `memory.limit()`??

Comment: @P.Paccioretti I don't know any people who work with systems that have some hundred millions TB of RAM. I wouldn't expect to meet someone working with such resources asking this kind of question on SO.

Comment: @P.Paccioretti indeed Roland is correct, I am not working with such resources. I guess the only solution to this would be to subset my data. However, for the previous code provided that Roland had answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431096/ssas-sexual-segregation-and-aggregation-statistic-in-r-calling-c , datasets of over 1000 rows worked with the chisq function.

Comment: Compare the output of `table` for the example with the output for your data (which you haven't shown).

Comment: Thank you for your help - this is now resolved - after comparing the data tables I noticed that mine was formatted wrong.